# Как избавиться от дерганости смены картинок

Tags: html, css, css3, изображения

Есть у меня 2 блока, которые по ховеру меняют картинку. При загрузке страницы и наведении на них смена происходит дергано и резко, пока картинки не сохранятся в браузер и дальше и благодаря свойству `transition` меняются плавно.

Как избавиться от дерганности смены картинок?

```css
#plasch1,
#plasch2 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto 20px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
#plasch1 {
  background: url(http://s019.radikal.ru/i625/1510/c8/9aacc300c120.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}
#plasch2 {
  background: url(http://s020.radikal.ru/i720/1510/02/bcd3fcaf61d5.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}
#plasch1:hover {
  background: url(http://s019.radikal.ru/i602/1510/96/342189e0bff2.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}
#plasch2:hover {
  background: url(http://s017.radikal.ru/i422/1510/a9/1cd5dc8beec1.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="plasch-items">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div id="plasch1"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div id="plasch2"></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: спрайтом сделайте обе картинки. или предварительно подгружайте вторую.

Comment: @Alexander Igorevich "или предварительно подгружайте вторую" а это как сделать? скриптом?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Дерганья происходят из-за того что второе изображение не загружается сразу, а только при появлении (то есть при наведении, в вашем случае).

1) Использовать технику sprite для изображения. Объединение многих изображений в одно. Почитать [подробнее](https://learn.javascript.ru/css-sprite)

2) Подгружать скрытые изображения при загрузке страницы.

Способ "в лоб":

```
<img src="http://s019.radikal.ru/i602/1510/96/342189e0bff2.png" style="display:none;">
<img src="http://s017.radikal.ru/i422/1510/a9/1cd5dc8beec1.png" style="display:none;">
```

Способ более хороший:

```
var images = new Array()
function preload() {
    for (i = 0; i < preload.arguments.length; i++) {
        images[i] = new Image()
        images[i].src = preload.arguments[i]
    }
}
preload(
    "http://s019.radikal.ru/i602/1510/96/342189e0bff2.png",
    "http://s017.radikal.ru/i422/1510/a9/1cd5dc8beec1.png"
)
```

3) и еще одно:

создать блок 1x1 пиксель. в него через запятую прописать все фоны, которые вам нужны.

```
<div class="preload"></div>

.preload {
    width:1px;
    height:1px;
    background-image:
        url(http://s019.radikal.ru/i602/1510/96/342189e0bff2.png),
        url(http://s017.radikal.ru/i422/1510/a9/1cd5dc8beec1.png);
    background-repeat:none;
    background-position:-1000px -1000px;
    position:absolute;
    opacity:0;
}
```

Comment: прикол в том, что например сервис http://csssprites.com/ создает  спрайт со всеми изображения в столбик и пака браузер доберется скажем до 2000 позиции все пролистывание отображается на экране..

Comment: значит для вас другие способы.

Comment: @Вася при использовании техники sprite отключайте анимацию на `background-position`

Comment: @korytoff т.е. теперь используя спрайты я не могу более гибко управлять анимацией `transition` `transform` и т.п. ?

Comment: @xaja получается, что используя самый изящный способ спрайтов теперь нельзя управлять анимацией без скриптов?..(

Comment: много разных способов. например, можно у дива сделать два псевдоэлемента `:before` и `:after`. в каждый прописать разные изображения. один скрыть через `opacity`, при наведении менять местами `opacity`. а что будет если по совету @korytoff отменить анимацию `background-position`?

Comment: @Вася можно. Используйте разные элементы для спрайта и анимации и вложите один в другой как например + я уже написал про отключение анимации для `background-position`. Прописывайте анимацию только для тех свойств, которые вам нужны

Answer (score 1):

Можно предзагрузить картинки в скрытый псевдоэлемент:

```
  body:after {
    content:
        url(http://s019.radikal.ru/i625/1510/c8/9aacc300c120.png)
        url(http://s020.radikal.ru/i720/1510/02/bcd3fcaf61d5.png)
        url(http://s019.radikal.ru/i602/1510/96/342189e0bff2.png)
        url(http://s017.radikal.ru/i422/1510/a9/1cd5dc8beec1.png);
    display: none;
  }
```

Не уверен, насчет всех браузеров, но в Chrome это точно работает.

UPD: В Firefox тоже работает.

```css
body:after {
  content:
      url(http://s019.radikal.ru/i625/1510/c8/9aacc300c120.png)
      url(http://s020.radikal.ru/i720/1510/02/bcd3fcaf61d5.png)
      url(http://s019.radikal.ru/i602/1510/96/342189e0bff2.png)
      url(http://s017.radikal.ru/i422/1510/a9/1cd5dc8beec1.png);
  display: none;
}

#plasch1,
#plasch2 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto 20px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
#plasch1 {
  background: url(http://s019.radikal.ru/i625/1510/c8/9aacc300c120.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}
#plasch2 {
  background: url(http://s020.radikal.ru/i720/1510/02/bcd3fcaf61d5.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}
#plasch1:hover {
  background: url(http://s019.radikal.ru/i602/1510/96/342189e0bff2.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}
#plasch2:hover {
  background: url(http://s017.radikal.ru/i422/1510/a9/1cd5dc8beec1.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="plasch-items">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div id="plasch1"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div id="plasch2"></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```