# Обновление фоновых изображений на странице без перезагрузки

Tags: javascript, html, css

Еще раз подчеркну: задача не стоит вывести рандомное изображение. Набор изображений и их адреса на сервере строго заданы.

Задача: обновлять картинки на сайте, т.к. содержимое файлов с изображениями может измениться. 
Физически файл с изображением остается лежать по тому же адресу, но т.к. содержимое файла может измениться, необходимо заставить браузер обновлять отображаемое изображение принудительно.
Для этого по таймеру добавляю параметр к адресу картинки

```
setInterval(function(){
       var arr = $(".image-responsive");
       for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ){
           arr[i].style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + arr[i].style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1).replace(/"/g, "").split("?")[0] +  "?" +  Math.random() + ')';
       }
}, 1000);
```

Изображения обновляются, но перед каждым обновлением происходит задержка и фон остается какое-то время пустым. Также фон появляется резко. Как это исправить, чтобы убрать дерганье и паузы?

Обновление 2:
Попытался использовать предзагрузчик - невидимый контейнер, в который подгружаются изображения, прежде чем установить их в качестве фоновых изображений для нужных блоков на странице.
С одной картинкой убрать дерганье получилось
http://jsfiddle.net/rGkww/36/
Однако дергается скроллинг. 
С несколькими http://jsfiddle.net/rGkww/41/ меняется только одна картинка, дерганье картинки по-прежнему, и скроллинг дергается

Обновление 3:
Вроде дерганье убрал, пример кода со множеством изображений
http://jsfiddle.net/rGkww/57/
Осталось дерганье скролла, ну и не совсем уверен в корректности самого решения. Страница должна быть рассчитана на длительную работу.

Обновление 4:
Убрал дерганье скроллинга
http://jsfiddle.net/rGkww/61/

Обновление 5:

Доработал немного код, чтобы в случае обрыва соединения с сервером не возникало переполнение памяти, и после восстановления обновление возобновлялось.
http://jsfiddle.net/rGkww/64/
Обновление происходит без проблем.
Однако `Iceweasel/Firefox` через пару часов падает. Т.к. необходима длительная работа, это критично. Неясно, проблема в коде или в браузере. `Chrome/Chromium` спокойно работает несколько дней.

Comment: наверное, это получается, потому что новый ФОН моментально не загружается (тупо трафик). Значит нужно предзагрузить изображения. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/455981/176892

Comment: @xaja поясните, пожалуйста. В моем случае каждый новый фоновый рисунок - для браузера по сути это новый файл. А по факту один и тот же. Заранее я по идее не могу подгрузить все варианты, т.к. смысл именно в обновлении фона. адрес картинки один и тот же, содержимое файла меняется, поэтому к адресу src картинки я добавляю параметр, чтобы браузер обновил фоновый рисунок. Трафик по идее не должен настолько влиять, что получается заметная пауза и дерганье, изображения небольшие, проблема точно такая же и на localhost

Comment: @xaja попробовал вот так: `arr[i].style.backgroundImage = arr[i].style.backgroundImage; `  и затем сразу `arr[i].style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + arr[i].style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1).replace(/"/g, "").split("?")[0] +  "?" +  Math.random() + ')';` Все равно фоновое изображение дергается

Comment: `?rand=24343243` и картинка загрузится ПОЛНОСТЬЮ по новой.  `?rand=4656345756` и это опять новая. с точки зрения браузера это каждый раз новое изображение. он каждый раз ее загружает заново. из-за этого и происходит. зачем вам вообще это нужно? дёргать одну и ту же картинку много раз?

Comment: @xaja содержимое файла с изображением периодически меняется, поэтому необходимо обновлять изображение на сайте

Comment: @xaja если просто сменить фон таким образом не получается без дерганья, что, если сделать дополнительный скрытый `img`, его `src` присвоить адрес нового изображения, и после загрузки взять этот `src` и установить в качестве фонового изображения для нужного блока? Только как поймать момент, когда `src` у скрытого `img` подгрузится? Что-то вроде события  `onload`. И `img` этот может ли быть `display: hidden`? Или тогда браузер не подгрузит изображение в кеш, и лучше просто сделать сдвиг этого вспомогательного `img` за рамки экрана, например, или сделать `z-index` для него под основным слоем?

Comment: ну собственно в правильном направлении мысль идет. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/455981/176892 и вот тут я уже описывал способы как загрузить скрытое изображение. По поводу `onload` - http://javascript.ru/forum/misc/8772-kogda-srabatyvaet-image-onload.html.

Comment: @xaja вот попытался сделать с одной картинкой, дергается меньше, в целом нормально http://jsfiddle.net/rGkww/36/ А с тремя не получилось, меняется только одна, и все равно дергается http://jsfiddle.net/rGkww/41/ Еще в обоих вариантах дергается скроллинг

Comment: Вам картинка нужна именно в фоне? Если это не принципиально, то можно размещать картинки в блоках, тогда и появление можно будет сделать красиво через fade.

Comment: @psaproxy к сожалению, именно в фоне, иначе никак

Comment: Зачем вы добавляется лишний элемент на страницу? Вам же уже написали, что можно обойтись лишь конструктором `Image()`. используйте его, не создавайте ни каких элементов, по событию `onload` уже вставляйте в фон картинку. На ваш вопрос уже ответили, но вы почему-то не хотите это признавать, настаивая на том, что бы изменили ВАШУ реализацию, хотя реализация _xaja_ работает

Comment: @ThisMan поясните, что Вы имеете в виду, когда пишите, что на мой вопрос уже ответили? Мне совершенно непринципиально, через `Image()` или каким-то другим способом решать проблему. Ответ, который размещен ниже от xaja, я уже прокомментировал, дерганье картинок не исчезло, т.е. проблема не решена

Answer (score 4):

Вот переделка вашего скрипта без дерганий. Изображения появляются только когда полностью загрузились. Вот что добавилось (прошу обратить внимание на то, что порядок строк очень важен):

```
var i = new Image();
i.onload = function(){alert(i.width);}
i.src = 'image.jpg'; // существующее изображение
```

Для демо версии так же прописал счетчик (увеличивающееся число), который показывает рассинхронизацию появления нового числа и изображения. Ну, вы же понимаете да, что для загрузки картинки браузеру нужно время.

п.с. я повторю еще раз - вы что-то не то делаете. Загружать ещё раз изображение, которое уже лежит в кеше браузера - не правильно. Никто так не делает. Наоборот пытаются предзагрузить все изображения, чтобы потом показывать их без дерганий ОДНОВРЕМЕННО с текстом.

п.п.с. если у вас задача выбрать 1 из миллиона изображений (то есть вы реально не знаете какое изображение к вам придет и именно это вы изображаете в данном вопросе с помощью `random()`), то тогда нужно в интервале сделать "шаг назад", то есть загружать БУДУЩЕЕ изображение (которое покажется в следующую итерацию). Пример давать сложно, потому что не известно каким образом в реальном проекте у вас контент обновляется. ajax?

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  var num = 0;
  var randomImages = ['344291068_HdnTo', '344290962_h6JjS', '344291168_nErcq'];
  setInterval(function() {
    var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomImages.length);
    var url = 'http://photos.smugmug.com/photos/' + randomImages[rndNum] + '-XL.jpg' + '?random=' + Math.random();
    var i = new Image();
    i.onload = function() {
      $(document.body).css({
        'background': 'url(' + url + ')' + ' no-repeat center center fixed',
        '-webkit-background-size': 'cover',
        '-moz-background-size': 'cover',
        '-o-background-size': 'cover',
        'background-size': 'cover'
      });
    }
    i.src = url;

    num++;
    $('#home').html(num);
  }, 3000);
});
```

```css
#home {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="home"></div>
```

Comment: спасибо, но картинки все равно дергаются, сравните визуально с вот этим вариантом смены картинок http://jsfiddle.net/rGkww/36/ про повторную загрузку я пояснил в самом вопросе

Comment: Пример кода в предыдущем комментарии приведен исключительно для визуального сравнения

Answer (score 2):

Таймер одноразовый, что бы между сменой изображений всегда было заданное время таймера (+время на загрузку изображения).

```js
var url = 'http://photos.smugmug.com/photos'
var images = ['344291068_HdnTo-XL.jpg', '344290962_h6JjS-XL.jpg', '344291168_nErcq-XL.jpg']
new updateBackgroundTimer('real', url, images, 1000)


function updateBackgroundTimer(node_id, url, images, timer) {
  // init
  node_id = String(node_id)
  var node = document.getElementById(node_id)
  if (!node) return false
  this.node_id = node_id
  this.node = node

  url = String(url)
  if (!images.length) return false
  for (var i in images) {
    images[i] = url + '/' + images[i] + '?r=' + Math.random()
  }
  shuffleArray(images) // вывод изображний в случайном порядке
  this.images = images

  timer = parseInt(timer)
  if (isNaN(timer) || timer < 1) return false
  this.timer = timer


  // model
  this.start = function() {
    initTimer()
  }

  this.stop = function() {
    if (this.timer_id) {
      clearInterval(this.timer_id)
      this.timer_id = null
    }
  }

  initTimer = function(_this) {
    return function() {
      if (_this.timer_id) {
        clearTimeout(_this.timer_id)
        _this.timer_id = null
      }
      _this.timer_id = setTimeout(

        function(_this) {
          return function() {
            _this.updateImage()
          }
        }(_this), _this.timer)
    }
  }(this)

  this.updateImage = function() {
    var url = this.getImageNext()
    var image = new Image()
    image.onload = function(_this, url) {
      return function() {
        _this.setImage(url)
        if (!_this.images_loaded) _this.images_loaded = {}
        _this.images_loaded[url] = true
        _this.start()
      }
    }(this, url)
    image.src = url
  }

  this.setImage = function(url) {
    url = String(url)
    this.node.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + url + ')'
  }

  this.getImageNext = function() {
    var images = this.images
    var images_qty = images.length
    var index = parseInt(this.index)
    if (isNaN(index) || index < 0 || index >= images_qty) {
      index = 0
    } else {
      index++
      if (index >= images_qty) index = 0
    }

    this.index = index
    var image = images[index]

    return image
  }

  function shuffleArray(array) {
    for (var j, x, i = array.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = array[--i], array[i] = array[j], array[j] = x);
  }

  // run
  this.start()
}
```

```css
#real {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="real"></div>
```

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора уточнить вопрос, оставьте комментарий к вопросу. Вы можете оставлять любое количество комментариев под своим сообщением. Когда ваша [репутация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [комментировать сообщения любого пользователя](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: ответ изменен для соответствия вопросу

Comment: @psaproxy спасибо, но задача вывода рандомных изображений не стоит. Перечитайте, пожалуйста, вопрос)

Comment: Можно использовать любые изображения, и не рандомные тоже

Answer (score 1):

> Обновление 2: .... С одной картинкой убрать дерганье [получилось](http://jsfiddle.net/rGkww/36/)
>   Однако дергается скроллинг.

Немного переписали Ваш код, убрали дерганье скролла, таким же образом код меняется и для нескольких картинок:

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  var randomImages = ['344291068_HdnTo', '344290962_h6JjS', '344291168_nErcq'];
  setInterval(function() {
    var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomImages.length);
    var src = 'http://photos.smugmug.com/photos/' + randomImages[rndNum] + '-XL.jpg' + '?random=' + Math.random();
    $(".preload_hidden").html("<img src=\"" + src + "\" />");
    $(".preload_hidden img").load(function() {
      var img = src;
      $("#real").css({
        "background": "url(" + img + ")"
      });
    });

  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.preload {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  #width: 1px;
  #height: 1px;
  background-repeat: none;
  #background-position: -1000px -1000px;
  #position: absolute;
  #opacity: 0;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
#real {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.preload_hidden {
  display: none;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="real"></div>
<div class="preload"></div>
<div class="preload_hidden"></div>
```

[**Пример на JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/g9bbdkxg/)

---

### **UPDATE**

*написали решение по вопросу автора*

```js
setInterval(function() {
  $(".real").each(function(index) {
    var obj = $(this);
    d = new Date();
    var bg = obj.css("background-image").match(/((http|https):\/\/.*(jpg|png|gif)).*/i)[1] + '?random=' + d.getTime();
    console.log(bg);
    $('<img/>').attr('src', bg).load(function() {
      $(this).remove(); // чтобы избежать утечки памяти
      obj.css('background-image', 'url(' + bg + ')');
    });
  });

}, 2000);
```

```css
.real {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  float: left;
}
.preload_hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="real" style='background-image: url("http://photos.smugmug.com/photos/344291068_HdnTo-XL.jpg");'></div>
<div class="real" style='background-image: url("http://photos.smugmug.com/photos/344290962_h6JjS-XL.jpg");'></div>
<div class="real" style='background-image: url("http://photos.smugmug.com/photos/344291168_nErcq-XL.jpg");'></div>
```

**[Example on Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g1th818s/)**

Comment: спасибо, у меня в Вашем примере картинки все равно дергаются. В вопросе добавил код со множеством картинок, дерганья нет, но опять-таки проблема со скроллингом

Comment: @Emm уточните пожалуйста под кодом со множеством картинок вы имеет ввиду обновление 3 - http://jsfiddle.net/rGkww/57/  ?

Comment: да, совершенно верно, этот код

Comment: да, все верно, для этого и приписывается `random` параметр

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31301/discussion-between-alex-and-emm).